# Одинаковое имя свойства и гетта, сеттера у класса в javascript

Tags: javascript, классы

```js
'use strict';

class UserService {
  username;
  password;

  constructor(username, password) {
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
  }

  get password() {
    return `getter ${this.password}`;
  }

  set password(v) {
    this.password = '000';
  }
}

const admin = new UserService('Fooman', '12345');
admin.password = '567890';

console.log('Username:', admin.username);
console.log('Password:', admin.password);
```

Почему можно указать геттер\сеттер и свойство с одинаковым именем. Причем геттер\сеттер не отрабатывают. Есть предположение, что метод записывается в прототип, а свойства перезаписываются при создании объекта.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields

Comment: Зачем предполагать если это прямым текстом в документации написано

Comment: потому что поле объявляется непосредственно в объекте, а свойства - в прототипе.

Answer (score 3):

Когда мне нужно иметь в классе геттеры и сеттеры, и при этом нужно еще хранить какое-то значение помимо геттера и сеттера, я использую приватные свойства с `#` в начале имени.

Напрямую к таким свойствам обратиться нельзя (только через геттеры/сеттеры).

```js
'use strict';

class UserService {
  // Приватные свойства класса должны быть перечислены в классе
  // в обязательном порядке
  #username;
  // Можно даже указыват начальные значения по умолчанию
  #password = [...crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(10))]
              .map(byte => byte.toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``;

  constructor(data) {
    if(data) {
      // методы внутри класса могут обращаться к полям напрямую
      if(data.username) this.#username = data.username;
      // а могут через геттеры и сеттеры
      if(data.password) this.password = data.password;
    }
    // Но вообще как правило, в конструкторе я делаю вот так:
    // Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  get username(){
    return this.#username || 'anonymous';
  }

  get password() {
    return `getter ${this.#password}`;
  }

  set password(value) {
    this.#password = `${value} setter`;
  }
}

const admin = new UserService(
   {username:'Fooman', password:'12345'}
);

console.log('Username:', admin.username);
console.log('Old Password:', admin.password);

// Снаружи класса можно обращаться только через геттеры и сеттеры
admin.password = '567890';
// Эта инструкция снаружи класса приведет к синтаксической ошибке:
//  console.log(admin.#password);

console.log('New Password:', admin.password);

let test = new UserService();
console.log('Username:', test.username);
console.log('Password:', test.password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Геттеры и сеттеры, как и любые другие функции - добавляются в прототип объекта, в то время как поля добавляются непосредственно в объекте.

Таким образом поля и геттеры/сеттеры никак не пересекаются и до геттеров/сеттеров просто не доходит выполнение, так как идет обращение напрямую к полю.

При этом к ним можно все еще обратиться - получив их из прототипа.

Для свойств нужно воспользоваться функцией [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor), чтобы получить объект содержащий описание нужного свойства, и у полученного объекта вызвать метод `.get`, передав ему в качестве контекста нужный объект:

```js
'use strict';

class UserService {
  username;
  password;

  constructor(username, password) {
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
  }

  get password() {
    return `getter ${this.password}`;
  }

  set password(v) {
    this.password = '000';
  }
}

const admin = new UserService('Fooman', '12345');
admin.password = '567890';

console.log('Username:', admin.username);
console.log('Password:', admin.password);
console.log('getter:', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(admin), 'password').get.call(admin))
```

Answer (score 0):

Считайте, что Вам повезло. Представьте, что работал бы геттер:

```js
'use strict';

class UserService {
  //username;
  //password;

  constructor(username, password) {
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
  }

  get password() {
    return `getter ${this.password}`;
  }

  set password(v) {
    this.password = '000';
  }
}

const admin = new UserService('Fooman', '12345');
admin.password = '567890';

console.log('Username:', admin.username);
console.log('Password:', admin.password);
```